# Emit() to everyone in /namespace - NodeJS, Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, namespaces

I have tried several variations of trying to emit to all users connected to a particular /namespace, but have had no luck. I could be misunderstanding how sockets work.

But what I have right now is two browsers open on different pages. When a user connects to pageA, that user is now part of '/users' namespace. When a user connects to pageB, that user is now part of '/valets' namespace.

I have a .emit() on pageA that sends to server.js. I listen for it with .on(), and then try to run .emit() but to only the users in '/valets' namespace.

I am able to see in my terminal "listening for request valet" and the console.log(data) part.

I believe my problem is the `usr_nsp.of('/valets').emit("incoming-request",{data:data});` portion. The other commented lines are what I have tried so far. They all give me an error:  is not a function.

server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});

var redis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis');


// create custom namespace for Users
var room_number;
var usr_nsp = io.of('/users');
usr_nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('user has connected to /users namespace');

    socket.on('request-valet', function(data){

        console.log("listening for request valet");
        console.log(data);
        room_number = data.room_number;
        socket.join(room_number);

        // usr_nsp.broadcast.of('/valets').emit("incoming-request",{repark:data});
        // usr_nsp.of('/valets').broadcast.emit("incoming-request",{repark:data});
        // io.of('/valets').emit("incoming-request",{repark:data});
        // socket.of('/valets').emit("incoming-request",{repark:data});
        usr_nsp.of('/valets').emit("incoming-request",{repark:data});

    });


});

var valet_nsp = io.of('/valets');
valet_nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('valet has connected to /valets namespace');

    // var room_number;

    socket.on('join-room', function(data){
        // assign valet to room
        room_number = data.room_number;
        socket.join(room_number);

        //valet_nsp.sockets.in(room_number).emit("request-accepted",{current_pos:current_pos})

    });

    socket.on('set-valet-starting-position', function(data){

        //var valet_starting_pos = data.starting_position;
        valet_nsp.sockets.in(room_number).emit('activate-directions-service', {repark:data});
    })

    socket.on('get-new-location', function(data){

        // send the updated location only to User
        // maybe use .broadcast??
        valet_nsp.sockets.in(room_number).emit("update-valet-location", {current_pos:data});

    });

});
```

pageB.html (sockets portion)

```
socket.on('incoming-request', function(data){

        console.log("incoming request");
        alert("incoming request");

        // use data to display on html screen


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace handle you created is used to [emit to users in that particular namespace](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#custom-namespaces%20emit). This should thus work:

```
var users  = io.of('/users'),
    valets = io.of('/valets');

users.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('request-valet', function(data) {
    valets.emit('incoming-request', { repark : data });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your method, no errors, but does not seem to listen on pageB client side. Nothing is being console.log.

Comment: @Chris and you have created client connection with `var socket = io('/valets');` and `var socket = io('/users');`? I tried with two HTML files and two namespaces and could emit without problems.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, I have on pageA: `var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/users');` and on pageB: `var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/valets');` I had previously tried `var socket = io('/users');` but that didn't work. I needed to add the 'http://...' part.

Comment: And just in case - you are loading pageB first and then pageA? Cannot guess much more based on the code above. Here's the test app though https://gist.github.com/vesse/ed1691160084aa7c15bb

Comment: pageA is being loaded first. your sample code is how i have mine set up too.

Comment: It could be the order I'm calling everything. Let me sort of organize the js blocks better. Thanks for the help though @vesse.